# Join multiple pandas dataframes by same column and summing

Tags: python, pandas

I have 100 panda's `DataFrames`. They have the same structure, two columns: `x` and `y`. I'm currently trying to `join` them all by the column `x` and calculate the average of column `y`s. Nevertheless, I'm facing a problem which is that the resulting `DataFrame` has only two columns `x` and `y` (instead of 100 `y` columns). I found that I should use `concat`, but it isn't working as I expected, any idea?

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

# ...

result = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=["x"], join="inner")

print result


#        x
#        x      y
# 0      0.120  687.46
# 1      0.122  691.03
```

Comment: How do you want to calculate an average - per column or per row?

Comment: I think you can improve the title of the question: "join multiple pandas dataframe by same column and summing"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.concat` concatenates dataframes along specified axis. Parameter `keys` should be used for multi-level axis.

try this instead:

Data:

```
In [26]: dfs
Out[26]:
[   x   y
 0  1  11
 1  2  12
 2  3  13,    x   y
 0  1  21
 1  2  22
 2  3  23]

In [27]: dfs[0]
Out[27]:
   x   y
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13

In [28]: dfs[1]
Out[28]:
   x   y
0  1  21
1  2  22
2  3  23
```

Solution:

```
In [29]: pd.concat(map(lambda x: x.set_index('x'), dfs), axis=1)
Out[29]:
    y   y
x
1  11  21
2  12  22
3  13  23
```

or using list comprehension:

```
In [34]: pd.concat([x.set_index('x') for x in dfs], axis=1)
Out[34]:
    y   y
x
1  11  21
2  12  22
3  13  23
```

Calculating average per **column**:

```
In [35]: pd.concat([x.set_index('x') for x in dfs], axis=1).mean()
Out[35]:
y    12.0
y    22.0
dtype: float64
```

average per row:

```
In [36]: pd.concat([x.set_index('x') for x in dfs], axis=1).mean(1)
Out[36]:
x
1    16.0
2    17.0
3    18.0
dtype: float64
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [8]: pd.concat([x.set_index('x') for x in dfs], axis=1).mean(1).reset_index(name='y')
Out[8]:
   x     y
0  1  16.0
1  2  17.0
2  3  18.0
```

Comment: I see, and how can I compute the average by row?

Comment: Just another question? How can I get a DataFrame as resulting object with both columns?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, what do you mean? Can you make an example?

Comment: I want to keep two columns in the resulting DataFrame x and y, where y is the average of all aggregated ys